# Auth event fired on every API call - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my EventServiceProvider

```
protected $listen = [
        'event.name' => [
            'EventListener',
        ],
        'auth.login' => [
            \App\Listeners\UserEventLoginHandler::class,
        ],
    ];
```

And this is my UserEventLoginHandler

```
class UserEventLoginHandler {

    public function handle($event) {

        $user = \Auth::user();

        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

        $user->save();

        $user_login_log = new UserLoginLog;

        $user_login_log->user_id = $user->user_id;
        $user_login_log->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $user_login_log->logged_in_at = Carbon::now();

        $user_login_log->save();
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is every API call, even if the user is logged in, this event runs. 
Shouldn't it run only when user logins for the first time?

Do I have to make some changes anywhere else? Or is there a mistake in my code somewhere?

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1/finance', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'sessionExpired']], function () {
    Route::get('/details', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\Finance\FinanceController@index']);
});
```

Comment: where does the script check if user is loged in?

Comment: That's the middleware, right?

Comment: What authentication driver are you using for in your API?

Comment: @MartinBean I am using Laravel Auth.

Comment: @phantomphoenix I get that, but which _driver_? Look in your **config/auth.php** file.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry. Eloquent.

Comment: If it is an API how are you maintaining sessions? Are you passing a token or something?

Comment: This is not a REST API. I was using Eloquent.